# error using text return type in $.post callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value, .post

My callback function returns data as text, but my callback function is not recognizing it and executes always the else condition.
 Here are my 'calling' parameters

```
$.post('ajaxupdate.php', data, handleAjaxResponse, 'text');
```

and my callback function is:

```
function handleAjaxResponse(response) { 
    if (response == 'worked') {
    alert("hi");
}else{
    console.log(response);
};

} // End of handleAjaxResponse() function.
```

and my php  `echo`es the string code on jQuery success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are echoing text/string, you can simply ignore the `text` option in ajax call, try this:

```
$.post('ajaxupdate.php', data, handleAjaxResponse);
```

Comment: @Bipin: Then there should be some other problem I think, make sure to check everything step by step, use console and there are no spelling mistakes probably.

Comment: i used log the response it prints the value fine but i am too frustrated with this

Comment: Do you get any response with your `console.log(response);`. What is the result of that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('ajaxupdate.php', function(data) {
  alert(data)
});
```

Try this cde it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You may have extra white space or line break being sent

Try:

```
function handleAjaxResponse(response) { 
    if ($.trim(response) == 'worked') {
        alert("hi");
    }else{
        console.log(response);
    };

} //
```

Ref:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/